# Clear grid when complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the word game I am creating the aim of it is to complete the words in the grid by dragging and dropping the corresponding letters. Doing this will result in the image behind the grid, being revealed.

At the moment the grid is populated by 6, 3 letter words (18 cells) and 18 blank cells.

So when words are completed they are styled to fade away. I then want the rest of the cells to fade when all the words are completed. How would I do this?

Here is the scrip for the drop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming here that "the rest of the squares in the grid" is all the table cells with the class `noglow`. In that case the code to make them all fade away will look something like this:

```
// Make all table cells with the class 'noglow' fade out over 0.5 seconds
$('td.noglow').fadeOut(500, function() {
    // Optional callback function for when the elements have completely faded out
});
```

Comment: the class is "noglow" for the rest of the cells @Codemonkey

Comment: @sMilbz: Edited the answer to comply

Comment: I don't know where to put the ".addClass('noglow')" in the script to affect the cells. Above is the script in the edited Q @Codemonkey

Comment: I don't know how the logic of your game works, but if all cells should have the `noglow` class by default, just add it to them in the HTML: `<td class="noglow">...</td>`

Comment: I have sorted that bit now. What would I write for the function? @Codemonkey

Comment: Do you mean the callback function? You don't have to put anything in there if you don't need to run any code after the blocks fade out. This is valid: `$('td.noglow').fadeOut(500)`

Comment: But the fade out needs to know when all the words are completed to fade the empty cells @Codemonkey

Comment: @sMilbz: Again, that's a game logic issue and not an issue on how to clear the table grid. In your question you ask "how to I get the rest of the squares in the grid to fade away and reveal the full image behind.", you don't ask how to detect when all the words in your game has been completed and I don't know if it's possible to answer that without much more knowledge about the logic of your game.